# Django does not append trailing slash automatically

Tags: python, django, redirect

I'm creating a website using `Django==4.2.3`, the problem I'm facing is when I visit a URL for example `http://127.0.0.1:8000/calculators` it sends me to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/calculators/` (it appends slash in the end as it should.

However in the production server it doesn't append the slash to URL. For example `https://example.com/calculators` throws a `404` instead of redirecting to `https://example.com/calculators/'`

I did not use the `APPEND_SLASH` setting as I think that's already true by default. Here is how my middleware looks like:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django_browser_reload.middleware.BrowserReloadMiddleware",
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Here is how I registered the URLs:

`calculators/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', CalculatorsView.as_view(), name='calculators'),
    path('stripe-fee/', StripeFeeCalculator.as_view(), name='stripe_fee_calculator'),
    path('fiverr-fee/', FiverrFeeCalculator.as_view(), name='fiverr_fee_calculator'),
]
```

`project/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('calculators/', include('calculators.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Please help me figure out how to solve this problem, thanks in advance!

## Solved

I don't know how they are related to each other but this is what I changed/fixed and it solved my problem.

My 404, and 500 routes did not initially return 404 and 500 statuses:

```
def page_not_found(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'pages/404.html', {})

def server_error(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/500.html', {})
```

I changed them to i.e. added appropriate status codes:

```
def page_not_found(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'pages/404.html', {}, status=404)

def server_error(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/500.html', {}, status=500)
```

Note: I did not used `APPEND_SLASH=True` in this case, doing above solved my problem!

Thanks to everyone tried to help on this!

Comment: One of your examples uses `http:`, and the other uses `https:`.  Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: of course the local dev server runs on http:, but I expect it to redirect me to "/" version URL in production. Just tried adding `APPEND_SLASH = True` but still doesn't work.

Comment: Then you must have some other difference in your dev vs production server.  I'm going to guess that, somehow, you have not deployed the exact same code on the production server.

Comment: Are you able to set DEBUG = True on the production server temporarily?  This might reveal the problem.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, however this still doesn't explain why it worked on dev but not production...

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough I had the same problem with 4.2.3 and your solution solved it!

My Custom Error Views did not return error statuses.

```
# Custom Error Views
def custom_page_not_found_view(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'core/404.html', {'title' : '404'})

def custom_error_view(request, exception=None):
    return render(request, "errors/500.html", {'title' : '500'})

def custom_permission_denied_view(request, exception=None):
    return render(request, "errors/403.html", {'title' : '403'})

def custom_bad_request_view(request, exception=None):
    return render(request, "errors/400.html", {'title' : '400'})
```

Solved it by adding the status.

```
# Custom Error Views
def custom_page_not_found_view(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'errors/404.html', {'title' : '404'}, status=404)

def custom_error_view(request, exception=None):
    return render(request, "errors/500.html", {'title' : '500'}, status=500)

def custom_permission_denied_view(request, exception=None):
    return render(request, 'errors/403.html', {'title' : '403'}, status=403)

def custom_bad_request_view(request, exception=None):
    return render(request, "errors/400.html", {'title' : '400'}, status=400)
```